# when using Spine.js and Hem, is there a way to stop it from compressing the Javascript?

Tags: build, spine.js

I am just starting out with Spine and am going for the default implementation of using Hem. I am basically running the "hello world" todo example app, but trying to substitute a server backend rather than local storage.

But when I run the application from hem, there is an error. Now the error is probably mine, but because the Javascript has been compressed it is difficult to debug. (Hem both compiles the coffee-script files and compresses them).

Is there a way to specify in something like the slug.json to not compress the files so that I can debug? I don't think compressing files is a default coffee-script compiler option so it must be either asking coffee to do it, or doing it itself.

Quite new to both the Javascript MVC world and to Coffeescript, but making headway until I get to debugging my first (of sure to be many) errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try

```
hem --debug=true build
```

Using this, hem will not minified the javascript produced.

Answer (score 1):

if debugging you are usually going to be using hem server functionality

in the more recent versions of hem --debug is aliased to -d

```
hem server -d
```